# Apache url call returns random 400 bad request

Tags: java, http, mod-rewrite

Currently Apache errors are giving me headaches.

Disable after entering [www.xxx.com](http://www.xxx.com)
xxx.com
Excluding www causes Bad Reuqest.
In Apache log

```
AH02032: Hostname xxx.com
The hostname www.xxx.com served over SNI and served over HTTP are different.
```

apache conf settings VirtualHost

```
<virtual host *:443>
Server name www.xxxx.com
Server alias xxxx.com
#ServerAlias ​​​​www.xxxx.com

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.xxxx.com$1 [R,L]

JkMount /home* worker2
JkMount /wcms* worker2
JkMount /ckupload worker2
JkMount /fip* worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

What I tried to fix the issue:

1. URL redirect call settings
2. Test after terminating load balancer web server 1,2
3. SSL Settings Delete

I need help. please.